# Add quotes to all words exluding ()

Tags: javascript

I have such a sentence:

```
(CAR AND BUS) OR TRAM
```

I need to add quotes to all words except AND(it can be OR instead of AND):

So I created such a code for that:

```
word.replace(/"/g, '').split(" ").map(e => ["AND", "OR"].includes(e) ? e : '"' + e + '"').join(" ");
```

but as an output, I have an incorrectly formatted query like

`"(CAR" AND "BUS)" OR "TRAM"`

I do need not to include quotes to the () so as an output I expect to have

```
("CAR" AND "BUS") OR "TRAM"
```

How can I achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(CAR AND BUS) OR TRAM".replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)/gi, function(word){ 
   if(["AND", "OR"].indexOf(word) < 0) return `"${word}"`;
   else return word 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of approaches to solve your task. Here is one that is more procedural and it does not use regular expressions.

Basically your task is to split the sentence into words, then process each word, checking if it requires processing and then apply your given ruleset.

Ofcourse this can be written more concise by using regular expression (see other answers) but especially if you have people around in your team that are not so versatile sometimes an more expressive approach is good too.

```
var sentence = "(CAR AND BUS) OR TRAM"; // Input data
var words = sentence.split(" "); // Get each word of the input
var exclude = ["AND", "OR"]; // Words that should be ignored when processing
var result = []; // result goes here
words.forEach(word=>{ // loop over each word
  if(exclude.includes(word)){ // exclude from further processing?
    result.push(word);   //yes: put into result
  } else{ //no: remove ( and ) and enclose with quoationsmark then put into result
    result.push("\""+word.replace("(","").replace(")","")+"\""); 
  }
  }
);
console.log(result.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace()`

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/1kC6zT/2

```js
console.log("(CAR AND BUS) OR TRAM".replace(/(?!AND|OR)(\b[^\s]+\b)/g, '"$1"'))
```